# Create transparent div on image hover with the exact dimension of the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'll explain my problem to you. I have a page where there are several images, each with a different size. I would then be able to create a class or something that allows me, passing over an image, to create a div above the image itself with a button inside it and an inscription without changing the page layout. In particular, it must have the button above and the writing below. Below is the code I used for the page currently without the effect of hover and a jsfiddle.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7k2803qn/2/).

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Find your PT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../index.html">Find Your PT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="ulNavBar">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-danger" href="../../php/view/loginSignup.html">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <header class="masthead">
        <section class="h-100 fullPageImage">
            <div class="row h-100 text-white font-weight-bold text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 h-50 my-auto">
                    <img src="https://img.wallpapersafari.com/tablet/2560/1700/56/31/wC2k5O.jpg" class="img-thumbnail h-75" alt="Profile Image" id="profilePicture">
                    <h1 class="text-uppercase border-bottom">
                        <span id="cognomeNome"></span>
                    </h1>
                    <h5>
                        <span id="descrizione"></span>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="upload1" id="uploadImageProfile" class="upload" multiple="multiple" />
                Massima dimensione delle immagini: 7mb

            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

```
.blurry-text {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.masthead{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.31) 0,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%);
}

.fullPageImage{
    background: url(https://img.wallpapersafari.com/tablet/2560/1700/56/31/wC2k5O.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row{
    margin:0 !important;
}

.flex-column {
    max-width: 260px;
}

img {
    margin: 5px;
}

.scale {
    transform: scaleY(1.05);
    padding-top: 5px;
}

body,html {
    height: 100%;
}

.v-center {
    position: relative;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}

.navbar-default{
    transition:100ms ease;
    background: #0000003b;
}
.navbar-default.scrolled{
    background:#000;
}

.label:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}

.hideme{
    opacity:0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .animate {
        animation-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0rem);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: transform;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-opacity: 1;
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1rem);
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
    }
}

.slideIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-name: slideIn;
}


.profileImage{
    border: 5px solid white;
}
```

So, passing over the central profile image, I would like the div that I described above to appear. If you succeed using an effect similar to effect 13 of the following page: https://miketricking.github.io/bootstrap-image-hover/#

But this is another problem that I can deal with, while creating the div above the image itself also involves unwanted layout changes in the way I did.

Added the 2 screenshot:
[image: good layout]

[image: Bad aspect ratio]

PS: Image Credit by [Gerd Altmann](https://pixabay.com/users/geralt-9301/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1373684) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1373684)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the expected result. What images you're taking about? The page's background? The smaller image? When you say `button` is that the upload button we can see or it should be a different one?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The image i'm talking about is the smaller one. And the upload button yes, it's the one that is already on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your question by modifying the existing code. Check out this snippet

```css
.blurry-text {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.masthead{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.31) 0,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%);
}

.fullPageImage{
    background: url(https://img.wallpapersafari.com/tablet/2560/1700/56/31/wC2k5O.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row{
    margin:0 !important;
}

.flex-column {
    max-width: 260px;
}

img {
    margin: 5px;
}

.scale {
    transform: scaleY(1.05);
    padding-top: 5px;
}

body,html {
    height: 100%;
}

.v-center {
    position: relative;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}

.navbar-default{
    transition:100ms ease;
    background: #0000003b;
}
.navbar-default.scrolled{
    background:#000;
}

.label:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}

.hideme{
    opacity:0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .animate {
        animation-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0rem);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: transform;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-opacity: 1;
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1rem);
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
    }
}

.slideIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-name: slideIn;
}


.profileImage{
    border: 5px solid white;
}

#profilePicture{
display:inline-block;
background-image: url('https://img.wallpapersafari.com/tablet/2560/1700/56/31/wC2k5O.jpg');
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border: 5px solid white;
width: 12em;
height: 9em;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hoverLayout{
visibility:hidden;
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#profilePicture:hover > .hoverLayout{
  visibility:visible;
  animation: slideIn ease-in-out .75s forwards;
}

.hoverLayout:hover{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Find your PT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../index.html">Find Your PT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="ulNavBar">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-danger" href="../../php/view/loginSignup.html">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <header class="masthead">
        <section class="h-100 fullPageImage">
            <div class="row h-100 text-white font-weight-bold text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 h-50 my-auto">
                    <div class="profilePicture" alt="Profile Image" id="profilePicture">
                    <div class="hoverLayout">
                    <h1 class="text-uppercase border-bottom">
                        <span id="cognomeNome">Title</span>
                    </h1>
                    <h5>
                        <span id="descrizione">Description</span>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="upload1" id="uploadImageProfile" class="upload" multiple="multiple" />
                Massima dimensione delle immagini: 7mb

            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the solution you posted, but using a div-background instead of an image actually created some trouble while trying to display the image at 100% of height and width of the div, problem that is not present while using img tag.

Comment: I get your problem, but ```background-size``` could take take care of that. You can specify the size of the background or set it to cover the div. In the snippet, I used cover

Comment: I tried like you said, but i can't get it right. I added 2 screenshot to the question, so that you can see that, when i'm using the div-background and size: 100% 100% (because i want to show the entire photo) the aspect ratio is not right. Meanwhile, using it as img, change the div size and the image is displayed properly. Thanks for your time.